# Kinetica Heatmap Not Displaying on Some Map Sizes

Tags: openlayers, wms, kinetica

I have a table with some geospatial data that I'm displaying on a heatmap in OpenLayers. It is working great on most screens, but on my ultra-wide monitor, when I full-screen my browser window, it disappears. I have other layers that are showing on the map, but the heatmap always disappears unless I shrink the window size.

I have tried changing WMS version and format parameters, but it didn't do anything.

Here's my code for the layer:

```
  window.app.layers.locationWms = new ol.layer.Image({
    name: "WMS",
    visible: true,
    opacity: 1,
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
      url: window.app.services.wms,
      params: {
        VERSION: '1.1.1',
        FORMAT: 'image/png',
        SRS: 'EPSG:3857',
        TRANSPARENT: true,
        STYLES: 'heatmap',
        LAYERS: table
      }
    })
  });
```

Comment: The server probably has a limit on the WIDTH in image requests.  Using TileWMS would get around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum width and height for a generated WMS image in Kinetica is 8192.  When the width on the screen is greater than that, you could either generate a smaller image and have OpenLayers stretch it, or have OpenLayers use tiling to generate smaller images, which it will then combine on the map.